# How to display HTML using .NET in an interactive way

Tags: .net, html, browser, hover

What I basically want to do is take some HTML and display it in a way that when you mouse over any element, the application can parse the HTML I'm pointing to.  I want to do this with C#/.NET Framework.

Using IE is fine in my project and I'll want to basically edit the HTML so that when i hover over a table for instance, the table's border with become bold and a different color.

**edit**
what I'm actually doing is downloading html from the internet and then processing it. I basically want a tool that can look at a web page, and then when i mouse over different elements, my application can parse the corresponding html

What's the best/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a C# .NET question as that is a server side technology. You need to look at Javascript and the ubiquitous answer to Javascript questions is to use jQuery. Have a look at the [jQuery hover events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) and you can write some code like this.

```
$("table").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("table_border");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("table_border");
  }
);
```

CSS:

```
.table_border {
    border: solid 3px red;
}
```

Comment: my mistake for not being more specific.  what I'm actually doing is downloading html from the internet and then processing it.  I basically want a tool that can look at a web page, and then when i mouse over different elements, my application can parse the corresponding html